# Accessing a variable in the parent AS3 script from a child script

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, parent-child, parent

I am having an issue passing the value of a variable in a parent AS3 script to a child swf called by the parent.

The child also has an AS3 script associated with it.

It is a simple example. Here is the parent script.

```
package scripts {
            import flash.display.MovieClip;
            import flash.display.*;
            import flash.net.URLRequest;
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;
            import flash.events.Event;

            public class passone extends MovieClip {

                public var topVariable;

                public function passone() {

                    var button: buttonMovie = new buttonMovie();
                    button.x = 300;
                    button.y = 400;
                    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClicked);
                    addChild(button);

                    topVariable = "Parent variable";
                }

                function onButtonClicked(e: MouseEvent): void {

                    trace("This is the variable: " + topVariable);
                    var myLoader: Loader = new Loader();
                    var url: URLRequest = new URLRequest("PassVariableTest2.swf");
                    myLoader.load(url);
                    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
                    //addChild(myLoader);

                    function onComplete(e: Event): void {
                        topVariable = "Parent variable";
                        addChild(myLoader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the code for the swf the parent calls.

```
 package scripts {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.text.TextField;
        import flash.events.Event;

        public class passtwo extends MovieClip {

            var topVariable

            public function passtwo() {

                //var ChildVar = MovieClip(parent.parent).topVariable;

                trace("This is being called");

                trace("The answer should follow: " +MovieClip(this.parent.parent).topVariable);
                //trace(MovieClip(this.parent));
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried several different configurations of the code to access the variable from the parent script.

```
MovieClip(this.parent.parent).topVariable
MovieClip(parent.parent).topVariable
MovieClip(this.parent.parent.parent).topVariable
MovieClip(this.parent).topVariable
```

I could really use some help figuring this out. 
I keep getting Error#1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cast to `MovieClip` really is one of those bad practices you can find all over the internet. It doesn't help with anything except obfuscating the problem even more, because all it basically does is prevent any compile time checks from happening, because `MovieClip` is a `dynamic` class.

From a design point of view, you do not want your loaded swf file to reach out and try to grab stuff from others.

Instead, define the behaviour in a desirable way. If your class needs a value, create a method so it can be passed to it. I use a set function here, so it can be used like a property.

```
package scripts 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class StringReceiver extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _text:String = "";

        public function StringReceiver() 
        {
        }

        public function set text(value:String):void
        {
            _text = value;

            // do stuff with the received string here, e.g.:

            trace(_text);
        }
    }
}
```

If you compile this into a .swf file and load it, you cast it to the class and not `MovieClip`. Also, don't nest functions into each other unless you know what you are doing.

```
package scripts 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;

    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _message:String = "message";

        public function Main() 
        {
            var button: buttonMovie = new buttonMovie();
            button.x = 300;
            button.y = 400;
            button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClicked);
            addChild(button);
        }

        private function onButtonClicked(e: MouseEvent): void 
        {
            trace("This is the variable: " + _message);
            var loader: Loader = new Loader();
            var url: URLRequest = new URLRequest("PassVariableTest2.swf");
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            loader.load(url);
            addChild(loader);
        }

        private function onComplete(e: Event): void 
        {
            var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;
            var receiver:StringReceiver = loaderInfo.content as StringReceiver;

            receiver.text = _message;
        }
    }
}
```

Also see: http://www.scottgmorgan.com/accessing-document-class-of-externally-loaded-swf-with-as3/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works kind of. I did find a couple of errors though. In the main script in the private function onComplete the var for receiver should be var receiver:StringReceiver = loaderInfo.content as StringReceiver. There was as space in the last StringReceiver.

And in the script for StringReceiver the 
public set function Text(value:String){ 
should be 
public function set text(value:String){
set was in the wrong place.
But I had no idea how to accomplish this without your help. And for that I really do want to thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @DavidYoung my bad, I should have mentioned that I just typed it out in browser to give an idea of how the solution can look like and didn't test it. Thank you for pointing those mistakes out, I fixed them in my answer. Feel free to directly edit posts next time. Editing other people's posts is encouraged on this site. Welcome to stackoverflow =)